# AWS RDS Database Version is different than Terraform version

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, version, amazon-rds

I'm learning how to use Terraform to manage my AWS Infrastructure.

Monday I created it all from scratch based on my Terraform Apply.

Tuesday (the next day) I wanted to update my app with some code changes (nothing that would affect the rest of the infrastructure, just my image in ECS) and got this error message in my terraform apply output:

```
Error: Error modifying DB Instance foo-staging-db: InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot upgrade postgres from 11.8 to 11.4
```

When I double checked my terraform `database.tf` I saw this:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "main" {
  ...
  engine                  = "postgres"
  engine_version          = "11.4"
  ...
}
```

Does anybody has an idea of what could have happened here?

1. This is not the first time that I update my databases like this, since I destroy my infrastructure every weekend to limit my AWS costs.
2. I solved the issue by changing my terraform Postgres version to 11.8, but still want to understand why the error happened in the first place.

Comment: RDS has a flag for automated minor version upgrades. Disable it if it's undesirable.

Comment: If you want to keep automated version and still have TF work, you can use `ignore_changes = "engine_version"`

Comment: Oh, interesting, thanks!
Is there a way to ignore only the minor version? If not I will probably prefer to disable the upgrades

Comment: You should be able to specify just the major version as the engine_version and then RDS will apply the ‘preferred’ minor version automatically.

Answer (score 6):

AWS use **default setting** `auto_minor_version_upgrade=true` and tries to update your database.
You can do following to solve it

**Method 1**

Set flag to false explicitly using `auto_minor_version_upgrade = false`

**Method 2**

Use **only first octet** in version number `engine_version = "11"`

For more information https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#engine_version

Comment: The editing queue is full, but `only first octet` I'm pretty sure the major version isn't an octet?